# Add 2 Numbers using linked lists - fail with large numbers - C

Tags: c, linked-list, sum, singly-linked-list, function-definition

On leetcode I have found the problem of adding two numbers using singly linked lists.
I'm still a beginner. I have written a code, which works for the first few testcases, but it fails with larger ones e.g.

```
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[5,6,4]
```

my output:

```
[-3,-4,-3,-5,-7,-7,-4,-5,-8,-6,-3,0,-2,-7,-3,-3,-2,-2,-9]
```

expected:

```
[6,6,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

my code:

```
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2)
{
    //extracting value of first list
    int cnt1 = -1;
    long long int sum1 = 0;
    struct ListNode *q = l1;
    while (q != NULL) {
        cnt1++;
        sum1 = sum1 + q->val * pow(10, cnt1);
        q = q->next;
    }
    printf("%d, %d\n", cnt1, sum1);

    //extracting value of second list
    int cnt2 = -1;
    long long int sum2 = 0;
    struct ListNode *p = l2;
    while (p != NULL) {
        cnt2++;
        sum2 = sum2 + p->val * pow(10, cnt2);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("%d, %d\n", cnt2, sum2);
    
    long long int finalSum = sum1 + sum2;
    printf("%d\n", finalSum);

    struct ListNode *retRoot = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    struct ListNode *t = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    
    //putting the final sum into the list

    long long int newSum;

    retRoot->val = finalSum % 10;
    retRoot->next = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newSum = finalSum / 10;
    if (newSum == 0) {
        retRoot->next = NULL;
        return retRoot;
    }
    t = retRoot->next;
    while (newSum != 0) {
        //printf("newSum: %d\n", newSum);
        t->val = newSum % 10;
        newSum = newSum / 10;
        if (newSum == 0) break;
        t->next = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        t = t->next;
    }
    t->next = NULL;

    return retRoot;
}
```

Comment: Now seems like a good time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement. I also recommend you use pencil and paper to draw up all list operations, with boxes for the nodes and arrows for the links. And then draw and erase arrows or boxes as you operate on the list.

Comment: By the way, you have multiple memory leaks in your code. That is, you allocate memory but then loose the pointer to it so it can never be passed to `free`.

Comment: Numbers are often limited to 64 bits... You may want to use some [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library like [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: The wikipages on [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming))s and on [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)s are relevant to your question. Compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Don't forget to read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Be aware that [malloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) can fail. Your code should handle that case. See also [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function initially is wrong at least because a list can contain a too big number that can not be stored in any fundamental integer type. So for example in this statement

```
 sum1 = sum1 + q->val * pow(10, cnt1);
```

there can be an overflow.

Or the memory allocation in this declaration

```
struct ListNode *t = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
```

produces a memory leak.

And moreover this code snippet

```
t = retRoot->next;
while (newSum != 0) {
    //printf("newSum: %d\n", newSum);
    t->val = newSum % 10;
    //...
```

results in undefined behavior.

The function can look the following way

```
struct ListNode * addTwoNumbers( const struct ListNode *l1, const struct ListNode *l2 )
{
    const int Base = 10;
    
    struct ListNode *head = NULL;
    struct ListNode **current = &head;
    
    int overflow = 0;
    
    for ( ; l1 != NULL || l2 != NULL; current = &( *current )->next )
    {
        *current = malloc( sizeof( struct ListNode ) );
        int sum = overflow;
        
        if ( l1 != NULL )
        {
            sum += l1->val;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }

        if ( l2 != NULL )
        {
            sum += l2->val;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
        
        ( *current )->val = sum % Base;
        overflow = sum / Base;
        
        ( *current )->next = NULL;
    }

    if ( overflow )
    {
        *current = malloc( sizeof( struct ListNode ) );
        ( *current )->val = overflow;
        ( *current )->next = NULL;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah now I see the overflow with the power function... since I'm still a beginner I have a hard time coming up with such a solution. I have seen a similar one elsewhere, but yours is truly direct.